# AS3 datagrid freeze pane / always show column in scrollable datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, show

Afternoon,
I have a datagrid with some custom renderrers and I'm just curious how I should approach the ability to freeze and always show the left 3 most columns at all times when scrolling left/right.

I thought that I might have to resort to 2 datagrids, side-by-side, the first showing the 3 columns that I want at all times, and the ability to scroll the rest. Only issue then I guess is linking the row selection to select that row in both and to tie the column sorts together...

Or would it be better to try and take columns 4+ and shrink their width to 0 as a person scrolls right, and then increase it back to the max width as they scroll left? Though that would cause funny issues to happen as the content of the datagrid would get smaller and smaller until you were 100% to the right and the scrollbar would disappear...

Any thoughts?
thanks,
jc

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Flex, the datagrid property you're looking for is called `lockedColumnCount`. If you set `lockedColumnCount="3"`, then the first 3 columns (from the left) of your data grid will always show.

Comment: Okay,
However I'm doing this in AS3 only. I've never touched Flex.
The title of the post started with AS3. However, that is a good start, I'll check to see if there is an AS3 equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, I made the assumption of Flex as normally a datagrid implies flex.